# How to edit thousands of html pages at once?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to edit thousands of pages for a website with dynamic content added manually by the owner throughout 3 years, it has thousands of pages and I'm sure there is a better way to edit them without spending hours opening each one of them.

I know it would be easy to just edit the styles.css but page dynamics like the positions of the google ad-boxes are individually edited inside the html of each page, so there is no way to solve this through css.

Is there some sort of code, script and macro that can edit the pages at once?

Answer (score 1):

> dynamic content added manually

So, you mean the content is *static*?

Providing there is at least some common structure to these pages then many code editors allow you to search/replace across multiple (hundreds, thousands, ...) files using regular expressions. Backup, backup, backup...

> the positions ... are individually edited inside the html of each page

By adding/removing HTML elements?!

If it's a case of overriding HTML attributes or inline styles then this can be achieved using a common stylesheet.

However, it doesn't take many global search/replaces across 1000's of files before it becomes more cost effective to redo the whole thing with some kind of templating system. (I worked on a site like that a few years - it absolutely did my nut!)

Comment: Yes they are static, and yes they are hard-coded individually inside each page, I need some kind of macro to automate the editing process for the thousand pages.